# Get an element's offsetHeight

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue.js component, which has large html template with images and different blocks.

```
<div>
   ...
</div>
...
<div class="image-block">
   <img src="..." alt="" width="..." height="...">
</div>
...
```

How can I get an image block's offsetHeight?

Comment: Where do you need to access that? In some event handler?

Comment: @NisargShah I need do this after loading the component in the browser and after that, I need to equate this image-block height to something div container. I'm trying to use the jquery code for this, but the task never worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it clearer for you:

```
mounted() { 

  let imageBlock = document.getElementsByClassName('information-block__img'); 
  // => A DOMElement set

  // If you want a jQuery set :

  let imageBlockJQ = $('.information-block__img') ;

  for (let element in imageBlock) { 

    let image = imageBlock[element]; 
    // So a DOMElement

    let imageHeight = image.offset();  // => FAIL

    // A DOMElement does'nt know the `offset` method. A jQuery set does
    // so:
    let imageHeight = $(image).offset();

    // Or

    let imageHeight = image.offsetTop ; // => RIGHT, a property

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `element.offset()` call.

Comment: `mounted() {
      let imageBlock = document.getElementsByClassName('information-block__img');
      for (let element in imageBlock) {
        let image = imageBlock[element];
        let imageHeight = image.offset();
        console.log(imageHeight);
      }
`
when I do something like this, browser show me this error:
TypeError: image.offset is not a function

Comment: before this, I'm trying to use `element.height()`, but the error was the same

Comment: Your problem, @СашаСеменец, is that you blind jQuery set and DOMElements lists… Either work with pure DOM element, either work with jQuery sets, but not twice in the same time. Often, property for the former is method for the latter.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, which works for me, but it works only when I'm resized a page:

```
mounted() {
      let infoBlock = document.getElementsByClassName('information-block');
      for (let element in infoBlock) {
          $(window).resize(function() {
              $('.information-block__container').height($('.information-block__img').height());
          });
      }
}
```

Comment: Why not simply: `$(window).resize(function(){$('.information-block .information-block__container').height($('.information-block__img').height())});`?…